# Como puedo convertir tiempo ldap/filetime de 18 digitos a fecha legible para humanos y/o a milisegunods?

Tags: ldap, directorioactivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda con esto por favor, e intentado convertir los 18 digitos sin embargo no funciona, si alguien tiene una idea se los agredeceria

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx. El código va como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes que tengas que transcribir :) Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que 
algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el 
(Recorrido de bienvenida) [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio 
y en (Cómo Preguntar) [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Comment: Pone el número que te da y la fecha que debería ser